# Making a POST request to PayPal checkout with PHP how to send authentication params?

Tags: php, authentication, paypal, guzzle

I'm using Guzzel to send a POST request to the PayPal checkout API. The documentation at PayPal is only for node.js here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/server-integration/#2-set-up-your-server-to-call-the-paypal-api

I'm trying to translate that into PHP with the following request:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$response = $client->post(
    PAYPAL_URL . 'payments/payment',
    [
        'auth' => [
            'user' => PAYPAL_ID,
            'pass' => PAYPAL_SECRET
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'intent' => 'sale',
            'payer' => [
                'payment_method' => 'paypal'
            ],
            'transactions' => [
                'amount' => [
                    'total' => $_SESSION['grand_total'],
                    'currency' => $_SESSION['currency'] === 'pound' ? 'GBP' : 'EURO'
                ]
            ],
            'redirect_urls' => [
                'return_url' => '',
                'cancel_url' => ''
            ]
        ]
    ]
);

var_dump($response);
```

I'm getting an authorization error like so

```
'Client error: `POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized`
```

So I guess I'm sending my authentication params incorrectly but I'm not sure how the PayPal API wants them formatting?

Comment: Why not use the Paypal PHP SDK? https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/

Comment: @FelippeDuarte from what I can tell that SDK only supports the legacy PayPal Express Checkout API (deprecated in 2017) and doesn't support the new PayPal Checkout Server Integration with the smart buttons https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#integration-options I could be wrong but the official docs only show how to integrate with node.js and even that has no SDK https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/how-to/server-integration/#1-set-up-your-client-to-call-your-server does this SDK support the PayPal Checkout Server Integration with the smart buttons?